# Google Maps Api v3 trigger issue, external link hit info window

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So my code looks like this, multiple markers:

```
var m1 = new google.maps.Marker(
   new google.maps.LatLng(35.2602340, -93.7939480), 
   {icon:tinyIcon,bouncy:1}
);

google.maps.Event.addListener(m1, "click", function() {
   m1.openInfoWindowHtml(   
      '1<br />test,TX'
   );
});

map.addOverlay(m1);

var m2 = new google.maps.Marker(
   new google.maps.LatLng(35.2810510, -93.8246510), 
   {icon:tinyIcon,bouncy:1}
);

google.maps.Event.addListener(m2, "click", function() {
    m2.openInfoWindowHtml(
        'test<br />test,Texas'
    );
});

map.addOverlay(m2);
```

How can I get this to work externally?

```
href="google.maps.Event.trigger(1, 'click');">Something</>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To trigger the click event on one of the markers, you can simply do:

```
<a href="javascript:google.maps.event.trigger(m1, 'click');">Trigger Click on m1</a>
```

However, it looks like you have some further problems in your code, because you're mixing methods from the [v2 API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/) and the [v3 API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/). For example, both the `addOverlay()` and `openInfoWindowHtml()` methods do not exist in the v3 API.

Therefore, your code should look something like this to work with the v3 API:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
   zoom: 11,
   center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.26, -93.80),
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

// You only need one InfoWindow object
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

// Create the markers, and keep a reference to them
var m1 = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(35.2602340, -93.7939480),
  map: map
});

var m2 = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(35.2810510, -93.8246510),
  map: map
});

// Add the events listeners on the markers
google.maps.event.addListener(m1, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.setContent('1<br />test,TX');
  infowindow.open(map, m1);
});

google.maps.event.addListener(m2, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.setContent('test<br />test,Texas');
  infowindow.open(map, m2);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you deal with large numbers of markers:

```
var map;
var markers = []; // declared EXTERNALLY (and m1 and m2 in the examples above)

function setupMarkers() {

    var markersLayer =  new Array();
    markersLayer = [
        [52.26326, 21.673675], // marker #0
        [52.67328, 21.865789], // marker #1
        [52.34366, 21.348797]  // marker #2 etc.
    ];

    for (var i = 0; i < markersLayer.length; i++) {
    // or: for (var i in markersLayer) {
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(markersLayer[i][0], markersLayer[i][1]);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({..., position: myLatLng, ...});
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {...}); 
        markers.push(marker);
    }

}

function initialize() {
    ...
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
    ...
    setupMarkers();
}

function launchInfoWindow(x) {
    // window.scroll(0, 0);
    // markers[x].setMap(map);
    google.maps.event.trigger(markers[x], "click");
}

HTML:
<a href="javascript:launchInfoWindow(2);">...</a>
```

Comment: i've got large numbers of markers on my map - is there any way around pushing all the markers to a separate array? Like can you assign all markers an 'id' property, and somehow 'get' by that id? ...or am I worrying over nothing - is it not much of a drain on resources to add all markers to an array...